# Record locking problem between linux and Windows

Tags: linux, foxpro, samba, cifs, clipper

I need to run a bunch of old DOS FoxPro / Clipper applications in linux under DOSEMU.
The programs access their "databases" located on a network server (could be a Windows or
Linux server)

Actually, the programs ran fine, but I cannot manage to make the record locking work
as supposed: I can run a program in two terminals (or the server and any terminal for
instance) and lock the same record in both.

Now, I'm using Tiny Core Linux as terminal and Windows XP as server, accesing the shared
files via CIFS and the latest DOSEMU (1.4.0), but I tried with various combinations of
server (Ubuntu 7 to 9, Damn Small Linux, XP) <-> protocol (CIFS, samba, various versions of smbclient) <-> client (same as server) with no luck

I tried to configure the server part to work without oplocks in samba (after reading the entire O'Reilly Samba book locking chapter in http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/ch05_05.html ) and in XP (\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\UseOpportunisticLocking = 0) but the problem persist.

Any ideas?

TIA,
Pablo

Comment: I dont know FoxPro or Clipper but is row locking really related with file locking?

Comment: Some locking information is at http://www.ghservices.com/gregh/clipper/netdlock.htm

Comment: Wish I had an answer for you but all I can extend is sympathy.  I've hit lock misbehavior trying to run stuff under Wine and never found an answer.

Comment: Can you run it under Wine instead of DOSEmu?  I'd be suspicious that DOSEmu wasn't designed with multiple DOSEmu instances in mind, so kept locking internal instead of using the host's file-locking system calls.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael: the programs works fine on any DOS (Lantastic, WFW) or Windows (95, NT, XP, ...) network.

I created a minimal C program to reproduce the behavior:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <share.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int handle, status;
 long length;

 handle = sopen("testlock.txt", O_RDONLY,SH_DENYNO,S_IREAD);

 if (!handle)
 {
    printf("sopen failed\n");
    exit(1);
 }

 length = filelength(handle);
 status = lock(handle,0L,length/2);

 if (status == 0)
    printf("lock succeeded\n");
 else
    printf("lock failed\n");

 printf ("Press a key...\n");
 getch();

 status = unlock(handle,0L,length/2);

 if (status == 0)
    printf("unlock succeeded\n");
 else
    printf("unlock failed\n");

 close(handle);
 return 0;
}
```

It works fine on DOS / Windows (the first terminal can lock, the 2nd one no), but fails executing in Linux under DOSEMU (you can concurrently run two instances of the program in a network share, and both can obtain the lock independently of the run sequence Linux-Windows / Windows-Linux).

Comment: Someone else had the same issue Oh does http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-msdos@vger.kernel.org/msg04683.html

Answer (score 0):

First off: Do these programs have any clue about locking? Are they made to be run with the db file on a network share?

Back in the DOS days, a network share wasn't real common (and when it was, it was Netware as often as not). If the database engine doesn't have any ideas that the underlying db file might be shared, then it doesn't matter what you with cifs - it's not locking, so it's not going to work.

Now, if you are already running this correctly on a network of DOS boxes and you are trying to upgrade to Linux, what's the current DOS network? Is it cifs, or is it more like Netware? Is there any chance that the database engine is aware of the network stack and doing something funny? That might lead to problems in a new environment where the db engine isn't aware of the network.

If you really need to figure out what's going on, you might try using Wireshark to trace the CIFS traffic and try to understand how it's using (or not using) locking. That's a big effort though, and unless you can generate some trivial apps to test with, then it's a lot of work.

Comment: Clipper was definitely used for multiple clients hitting one network share both Novell and MS-Net (I used dos ms net)

Comment: FoxPro obviously has a clue about locking, giving the thousands of multi-user systems out there using it. However there are some kludges involved which may or may not work under DOSEmu. See http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:g4q-AkJPCnkJ:ftp://www.alaska-software.com/documents/About_Locking.pdf+foxpro+offset+locking&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this problem does exist as indicated above. One solution is to move the shared DBF files off of the windows server and onto a linux server. these files can then be shared via CIFS (SAMBA) to interested windows parties and vi NFS (with the -o sync nolock options) to interested linux parties. 
It works for us quite well

Brett

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be [a known, ongoing issue](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=1954421&group_id=49784&atid=457448).

I do know that byte-range locking (aka Windows-style record locking) requires recent kernel versions, although I don't know if it appeared in the 2.4 series or not.

If DosEMU cannot be made to work for you, you might have to resort to something a little more "exotic".  Perhaps running [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) under a [KVM virtual machine](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Guest_Support_Status) would get you closer to your goals, although you'll have to do some manual setup to get networking support (that or figure out how to make a network share appear as a local drive letter in the guest).  Scroll to the bottom of the KVM compat list to see the status of various DOS-like installs.

If you have the original 6.22 installs to work with then that might actually be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

We run a dos epos application on a samba share with both windows 98,Xp workstations with the correct locking setting on the samba share we are also able to run the application through dosmeu. There are a range of lock setting on the samba share we used the following settings.

```
 [data]
        comment = data Share
        inherit acls = Yes
        path = /data/
        read only = No
        oplocks = no
        locking = Yes
        strict locking = No
        create mask = 0774
        directory mask = 0775
        browseable = Yes
        default case = upper
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite simple: posix locks
are not suitable for that task. And this is all we
had until late 2014, when linux-3.15 and glibc-2.20
started to provide OFD locks - 5 years after this
question was asked here.

CIFS only got OFD locks in 2018:
https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-cifs/msg14795.html

dosemu2 has experimental OFD locks support in git (2020).

So, to answer your question: the technologies
of 2009 (when that question was posted) were not
advanced enough to perform your task. In fact,
the work was started only 5 years later, when
linux got OFD locks, and it took 6+ years for
all other involved software components to catch
up.

Note: besides record locking, foxpro/clipper are
also "interested" in a so called "share support" -
another technology from MS, that is inherently
incompatible with posix. Share support will not
work in your scenario even now. At best, you can
get proper share support between multiple dosemu2
sessions running on the same machine. But you won't
get share if you open your files on your windows
server and under dosemu2 at the same time. And
even if you run several dosemu2 instances on
different machines, share support is not guaranteed
to work. But if all you need is region locking,
then it will work in all configurations, in case
your software is recent enough.